# Dialog('close') not working in IE8 JQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to close a dialog, in Chrome it's working fine but in IE dont work.
The code that i used is the below,

```
jq('#mydialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    width:500,
    height: 350,
    dialogClass: 'pcrTermsDialog',
    buttons: [{
                alt: jq("#mydialog .closeControl").attr("title"),
                title: jq("#mydialog.closeControl").attr("title"), 
                click: function() { jq(this).dialog("close"); }
             }]
});
```

Comment: No, doesn't show any console error, for example if i use jq(#mydialog).dialog("open") this it's working to open dialog, but if i use to close jq(#mydialog).dialog("close") dont work.

Comment: Can we see some HTML?  And what version of jQuery?

Comment: Ok permit me one minute to update the code, and jQuery version is 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "jq" is the var for the jQuery.  Try to make the button this way:

```
     buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $("#mydialog.closeControl").dialog("close");
            }
```